# I am not able to install react packages

Tags: reactjs

```
PS C:\Users\Aradhya\Desktop\rect-folder> npx create-react-app 01basicreact
(node:26512) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit   
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:26512) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit   
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Aradhya\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Aradhya\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Aradhya\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-05T04_18_23_516Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\Aradhya\Desktop\rect-folder>
```

actually I am unable to install react packages I want to use react concept on my visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

try

```
npm install {package} --force
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing is related to a potential memory leak in Node.js, where too many listeners are being added to an EventEmitter. However, the main issue seems to be that npm is unable to find a file or directory. This could be due to several reasons such as incorrect path, permission issues, or a problem with your npm installation.

Here is some solution i can give;

1. Make sure you're using the latest versions of Node.js and npm. You can check your versions by running `node -v` and `npm -v` in your terminal. If you're not using the latest versions, you can update them. You can update Node.js by downloading the latest version from the official website, and you can update npm by running `npm install -g npm`.
2. Make sure the path you're using in the command is correct. The error message indicates that npm is trying to find a file or directory at `C:\Users\Aradhya\AppData\Roaming\npm`, but it can't find it. If you're not sure about the path, try running the command in a different directory to see if it works.
3. If the problem persists, you might want to try reinstalling npm. You can do this by first uninstalling npm using `npm uninstall -g npm`, and then reinstalling it using `npm install -g npm`.
4. The warning message suggests increasing the limit of listeners. You can do this by running `require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 100;` at the beginning of your script. This will increase the maximum number of listeners to 100.
5. If you're still having trouble, it could be a permissions issue. Make sure you have the necessary permissions to read and write to the directories.

Once you've resolved these issues, you should be able to create a new React application using the `npx create-react-app` command. If you're still having trouble, please provide more information about your setup, such as your operating system, Node.js version, and npm version.